# find if value exist in php into mysql built array

Tags: php, arrays

i build an array from mysql this way

```
$q="select account_code from chart_master;";
// Generate resultset
$result_set = $con->query($q);

$list = Array();
while( $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set) ) {
   $list[] = $myrow;
}
```

when i dump $list i get:

```
array(79) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "11011001" ["account_code"]=> string(8) "11011001" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "11011002" ["account_code"]=> string(8) "11011002" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "11011005" ["account_code"]=> string(8) "11011005" } ...
```

i now want to check if a value is found in the values 11011001, 11011002 etc with this code:

```
if (in_array($row['1'], $list))
{
echo $row['1']." found in the array";
}
```

with $row['1'] being one of the searched value.

I guess I am not looking at the right depth in the array because my in_array does not return anything.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should go through each element of your `$list` array and apply `in_array` to it.

```
foreach($list as $listItem){
   if(in_array($row['1'], $listItem)){
       echo $row['1']." found in the array";
   }
}
```

`in_array()` only checks one dimension. That's why you need to go iterate through the first dimension and apply it to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct version of this I can imagine would be:

```
$exists = array_search('1001010101', array_column($list, 'account_code')) !== false;
```

This grabs the `account_code` column from the multidimensional array and looks inside that column for the value provided. If you only need an existence check, this seems to be a fast way of doing it.

However, if you don't need the rest of that SQL result set, I'd look into maybe doing a `COUNT()` or using a `WHERE` to narrow the result set instead. That would be more resource efficient.